# How to create a working login using rails api and nuxt js

Tags: devise, jwt, nuxt.js, rails-api

Im building a website using Nuxt Js and Rails Api. My rails api uses devise-jwt gem for authentication and it works correctly in postman. I receive a response in my headers with my bearer token. The problem is that I cant figure out how to set this up with my Nuxt app. I know nuxt has the $auth module that has methods like login and logout and for some reason those work, I still don't understand how $auth works.

I'll show you what my app can do up to now

When I sign in I try this...
POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/sign_in
with the email and pass in the body

And i get a json response and these headers in Postman

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "name": "David",
    "last_name": "Cantu",
    "username": "davidcantum",
    "created_at": "2019-03-21T18:29:09.494Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-03-21T18:29:09.494Z"
}
```

Headers

```
Location →/
Content-Type →application/json; charset=utf-8
Authorization →Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwic2NwIjoidXNlciIsImF1ZCI6bnVsbCwiaWF0IjoxNTYzMDQyNzIyLCJleHAiOjE1NjMxMjkxMjIsImp0aSI6IjdkOTE2YTg2LTM5MjEtNGY3My1hMmM0LTExNGU1Mzc3MGUwMyJ9.ortrSW8NPtHqtWfu1SFfNZoGEuS7tw9NHUd4kNW66y4
ETag →W/"77633a3c23a2ffcea1bdf28cbb86a42e"
Cache-Control →max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id →dff8218d-32f6-43b5-983f-2f4d9b40d8d4
X-Runtime →0.371214
Vary →Origin
Transfer-Encoding →chunked
```

This is what I have in my nuxt project

nuxt.config.js

```
auth: {
    redirect: {
      login: '/login',
      logout: '/',
      callback: '/login',
      home: '/'
    },
    strategies: {
      local: {
        endpoints: {
          login:  { url: '/users/sign_in', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
          logout: { url: '/users/sign_out', method: 'delete' },
          user:   { url: '/me', method: 'get', propertyName: 'data' }
        },
        tokenRequired: true,
        tokenType: 'Bearer'
      }
    }
},
axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1',
},
```

In the auth configuration you see I have user: .. /me and when I try to sign in I think it tries to get /me from the api but that route requires that you are signed in to enter, of course it does not work right now.

And also this is the method I use to try the login

```
async login() {
      try {
        await this.$auth.loginWith("local", {
          data: {
            user: {
              email: this.form.getFieldValue("email"),
              password: this.form.getFieldValue("password")
            }
          }
        });
        this.$toast.success("Logged In!");
      } catch (e) {
        this.$toast.error("Error while authenticating");
      }
    }
```

When I enter email and pasword and try to login I debugged this method and if I try this.$auth.state.loggedIn it is true! I dont know why :(

It does create a jwt in the rails backend but when I try to make another request to the API that requires authorization for example to the groups controller it wont work and Im not sure how to set those headers. The truth is Im looking at the documentation for the nuxtjs auth module but this part I need is not explained I guess?

Update:
I decided to use Doorkeeper as authentication. It was way easier to integrate.